# Net Link Linux User code bind socket call always fail for multicast group Id (non zero value)

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel, netlink

Hi am trying to implement net link user code and kernel code every thing works fine for unicast (src_addr.nl_groups = 0;). For mulicast, user code bind call always fails for non zero src_addr.nl_groups value. Really am not sure what value to put for multicast and how to proceed further. I checked the usage of netlink_broadcast in kernel source tree, so I put the same group Id value (RTMGRP_LINK) here. For unicast I found good number of help in internet but for multicast I don't think so . So Please help me to proceed further.

Error am getting is:

bind: No such file or directory

./a.out: can't bind socket (3)and err : -1: No such file or directory

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>
#define NETLINK_TEST 28
#define GROUP_IB 1
#define MAX_PAYLOAD 1024
struct sockaddr_nl src_addr, dst_addr;
struct nlmsghdr *nlh = NULL;
struct msghdr msg;
struct iovec iov;
int sock_fd;


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int err;
    sock_fd = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_TEST);
    if (sock_fd<0) {
            char s[BUFSIZ];
            sprintf( s, "%s: can't assign fd for socket", argv[0] );
            perror(s);
            return -1;
    }

    memset(&src_addr, 0, sizeof(src_addr));
    src_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    src_addr.nl_pid = getpid();
    src_addr.nl_groups = 0; // Unicast
    //src_addr.nl_groups = RTMGRP_LINK; /* Multicast, bind call always fails for non zero values */

    err = bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&src_addr, sizeof(src_addr));
    perror("bind");
    if (err<0) {
            char s[BUFSIZ];
            sprintf( s, "%s: can't bind socket (%d)and err : %d", argv[0], sock_fd,err );
            perror(s);
            return -1;
    }

    memset(&dst_addr, 0, sizeof(dst_addr));
    nlh = (struct nlhmsghdr *) malloc(NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD));
    memset(nlh, 0, NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD));

    iov.iov_base = (void *)nlh;
    iov.iov_len = NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD);
    msg.msg_name = (void *)&dst_addr;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(dst_addr);
    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;


    printf("pid : %d\n Waiting for messages from kernel...\n",getpid());
    recvmsg(sock_fd, &msg, 0);
    printf("Message : %s\n", NLMSG_DATA(nlh));
    close(sock_fd);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Netlink socket binds are sensitive to what USER you are- I've seen them reliably fail if you are not running the program in question as 'root', at least on RedHat 6.

Try running as root 1st, before changing your logic. If you get the same failure as you do in normal operation, then you know it isn't (necessarily) a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is

sock_fd = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_TEST);

Does you kernel module define the NETLINK_TEST family? your own family might must be supported at kernel module and it should post the message in the proper group using `nlmsg_multicast()`
RTMGRP_LINK is group defined in NETLINK_ROUTE.

This sample code is example for multicast

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <linux/netlink.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 #define MYPROTO NETLINK_USERSOCK
 #define MYMGRP 21

 int open_netlink(void)
 {
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_nl addr;
    int group = MYMGRP;

    sock = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, MYPROTO);
    if (sock < 0) {
        printf("sock < 0.\n");
        return sock;
    }

    memset((void *) &addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    addr.nl_pid = getpid();

    /* addr.nl_groups = MYMGRP; */

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        printf("bind < 0.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (setsockopt(sock, 270, NETLINK_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &group, sizeof(group)) < 0) {
        printf("setsockopt < 0\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return sock;
}

void read_event(int sock)
{
    struct sockaddr_nl nladdr;
    struct msghdr msg;
    struct iovec iov;
    char buffer[65536];
    int ret;

    iov.iov_base = (void *) buffer;
    iov.iov_len = sizeof(buffer);
    msg.msg_name = (void *) &(nladdr);
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(nladdr);
    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;

    printf("Ok, listening.\n");
    ret = recvmsg(sock, &msg, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
        printf("ret < 0.\n");
    else
        printf("Received message payload: %s\n", NLMSG_DATA((struct nlmsghdr *) &buffer));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nls;

    nls = open_netlink();
    if (nls < 0)
        return nls;

    while (1)
        read_event(nls);

    return 0;
}
```

kernel module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <net/netlink.h>
#include <net/net_namespace.h>


#define MYPROTO NETLINK_USERSOCK

#define MYGRP 21

static struct sock *nl_sk = NULL;

static void send_to_user(void)
{
    struct sk_buff *skb;
    struct nlmsghdr *nlh;
    char *msg = "Hello from kernel";
    int msg_size = strlen(msg) + 1;
    int res;

    pr_info("Creating skb.\n");
    skb = nlmsg_new(NLMSG_ALIGN(msg_size + 1), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!skb) {
        pr_err("Allocation failure.\n");
        return;
    }

    nlh = nlmsg_put(skb, 0, 1, NLMSG_DONE, msg_size + 1, 0);
    strcpy(nlmsg_data(nlh), msg);

    pr_info("Sending skb.\n");
    res = nlmsg_multicast(nl_sk, skb, 0, MYGRP, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (res < 0)
        pr_info("nlmsg_multicast() error: %d\n", res);
    else
        pr_info("Success.\n");
}

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    pr_info("Inserting hello module.\n");

    nl_sk = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, MYPROTO, NULL);
    if (!nl_sk) {
        pr_err("Error creating socket.\n");
        return -10;
    }

    send_to_user();

    netlink_kernel_release(nl_sk);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    pr_info("Exiting hello module.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```